# Hot to generate a windows app with flutter working outside the appstore

Tags: windows, flutter, pfx

I want to a windows installer (msix) and folowed the tutorial on https://docs.flutter.dev/desktop#msix-packaging
there -> "Use the following instructions to generate a self-signed .pfx certificate".

I cannont install the app even on my local machine as "This app package is not signed with a trusted certificate."

The tutorial says "Distributing your application by self hosting it on a website requires a certificate signed by a Certificate Authority known to Windows".

How cam I get/create a "certificate signed by a Certificate Authority known to Windows"?

Comment: I use InnoSetup to create windows installer. You can follow this tutorial https://retroportalstudio.medium.com/creating-exe-executable-file-for-flutter-desktop-apps-windows-ea7c338465e

Comment: did you find a solution for this issue?
my Windows program encounters an unknown publisher message during installation
I have not found a suitable way to create a cert file

Comment: No... I ended up in providing the app via the microsoft app store.